# getting error message from Python and selenium test

Tags: python, selenium

Why I'm getting this error message when i run Python and Selenium code?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\suthananthansa\Desktop\Sel\long.py", line 23, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="crmGrid_SavedNewQuerySelector"]/span[1]')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 354, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 832, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="crmGrid_SavedNewQuerySelector"]/span[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.104)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

This is my code. program runs until this "//*[@id='ewrb_importfile']" and throws an error message
**Code:**

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# from selenium.webdriver.ie.webdriver import WebDriver as DEFAULT_PORT
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python27\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://intra.dev.hscrm.com/QA")
# driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(25)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TabSFA']/a/span/span").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(60)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ewrb_importfile']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='crmGrid_SavedNewQuerySelector']/span[1]").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.close()
```

**Elements**
how do i find the correct Xpath?

```
<div id="commandContainer1" style="display: inline;">
<ul class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" role="application">
<li id="ewrb_importfile|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.ewrb_importfile.NewRecord" class="ms-crm-CommandBarItem ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu ms-crm-CommandBar-Button" tabindex="-1" title="New Create a new Import File record." command="ewrb_importfile|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid" style="white-space: pre-line; display: inline-block;">
<span class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered" tabindex="-1" style="max-width:200px">
<a class="ms-crm-Menu-Label" tabindex="0" onclick="return false">
<img class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-New_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16" tabindex="-1" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" style="vertical-align:top"/>
<span class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" tabindex="-1" style="max-width:150px" command="ewrb_importfile|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid"> New </span>
<div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible"> Create a new Import File record. </div>
</a>
</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Please provide a clear example of your problem (with your code...)

Comment: The error indicates that `//*[@id="crmGrid_SavedNewQuerySelector"]/span[1]` XPATH is not leading to any element on the page at that moment

Comment: It says why in the error.  Change your xpath.

Comment: how do i find here:

<a id="crmGrid_SavedNewQuerySelector" class="ms-crm-View-Name ms-crm-View-Name-View-Lite-hover" style="position: relative;text-decoration: none" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" title="Select a view" tabindex="0" gridid="crmGrid">

Comment: <span class="ms-crm-View-Name ms-crm-ViewSelector-title-associated-lite ms-crm-TextAutoEllipsis" currentview="{B28E651B-94AE-4B62-917C-9C79A2CDE5A5}" defaultsavedqueryview="{B28E651B-94AE-4B62-917C-9C79A2CDE5A5}" userselecteddefaultview="" userownedview="" quickfindquery="{EC29EE1D-03B8-4DAC-87F8-1267423046D2}" currentviewtype="1039" style="width: auto;">Active Import Files</span>

Comment: why don't you install the browser plug-in frebug and firepath (for firebug)? in this way you can easily inspect the elements and get directly from the plug-in the ID or CSS or Xpath

Comment: Hi Carlo. I'm using Firebug and fire path too. but Selenium doesn't take those values. I'm thinking is there any way to modify the Xpath?

Its hard to identify the element, its under div,div, li, span, a